# How to validate Email Addresses and store as encrypted in DB using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I want to validate the Email addresses being input in my ASP.NET MVC project at the Client Side. Then I want to save these to the database in an encrypted form.

I tried using

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
```

The problem is complicated by the fact that this data is being encrypted before storing in the database in the Constructor:

```
Email = Encrypt(email);
```

Now I have a problem presumably because the encrypted email addresses in the database are no longer valid.

I tried just validating a Decrypted version:

```
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string DecryptedEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return Decrypt(Email);
        }
    }
```

and I changed it on the View screen:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecryptedEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

This caused an exception when executing db.SaveChanges():

```
{"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."}
```

Inspecting the EntityValidationErrors, I can see my error message:

```
Invalid Email Address
```

Is there a way I make this method work solely on input?

Comment: Please post exception message.

Comment: I have amended the post to give details of the error message. It was an invalid email address I was trying to test, but I was expecting the error to be displayed after clicking submit.